# Check if boolean is true or false

Tags: php, boolean

I have this little part of code:

```
$company = array('relation' => $_SESSION['username']);
$companyresponse = $wcfclient->GetCompany($company);
    foreach ($companyresponse->GetCompanyResult as $key => $value){
    echo $value[0]; //This is the name of the company

    if ($value[1] == TRUE){
       echo "Company blocked";
    }
    elseif($value[1] == FALSE){
       echo "Company NOT blocked";
    }
    echo $value[1]; //This gives me the correct result, in this case: FALSE
```

The result of $value[1] is FALSE, though when it passed my if-statement it returns: "Company blocked" , so $value[1] is TRUE while it needs to be FALSE.

Can someone tell me why it doesn't return the correct value?

I also tried it with:

```
if ($value[1] == 1){
   echo "Company blocked";
}
else{
   echo "Company NOT blocked";
}
```

This gives me the value FALSE, but somehow the if-statement changes it into TRUE.

```
var_dump($value[1])
```

When I try a company which is blocked normally it gives me the correct result of:

`string(4) "True" Company blockedTrue`

Comment: add a `var_dump($value[1])` before the `if` statement to be sure about the value. Also use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: what is the outcome when you use if($value[1]){echo "Company blocked";}else{echo "Company NOT blocked";}

Comment: This gives me the result: string(5) "False" False , and no values of my echo when I change == into ===

Comment: if($value[1]){}else{} gives me an empty result

Comment: I mean, what is the outcome when you use if($value[1]){echo "Company blocked";}else{echo "Company NOT blocked";}

Comment: This gives me the result: Company blocked , which is not the correct value in this case.

Comment: Please note, the String "FALSE" is different from the value FALSE.  Also, if/else conditions test for TRUE or FALSE values.  Any other values are coerced into these values (which is bad style for the most part, in my opinion).  More information on booleans in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php.  **In response to your edit**:  A string(5) "False" is a **string** of 5 characters.  It **is not** the boolean value FALSE.  If it were the boolean value FALSE, it would state boolean instead of string.  The string "False" will evaluate to TRUE, since it is not an empty string.

Comment: @BLaZuRE , I've read anything about it on PHP.net , also normally I don't have any problems with booleans since I just do it with if($value[1]){} else{}  but somehow this all doesn't work right now.

Comment: When I try a company which is blocked normally it gives me the correct result of: string(4) "True" Company blockedTrue

Comment: @Marijke Any string, which is **not** the empty string `""` or string zero '"0"` will evaluate to TRUE.  This means `"hello"`, `"true"`, `"false"`, `"foo bar"` all evaluate to TRUE, it doesn't matter what the string itself says.  In other words, `"True"` evaluates to TRUE and `"False"` evaluates to TRUE.

Comment: @BLaZuRE , then how can I get this to work? In the DB it's stored as 0 and 1, and gives a True or False result. When I check if $value[1] == "FALSE" or "TRUE" it still doesnt give me the correct results.

Comment: can you show the code where `$value` is set/initialized.

Comment: @NiteshMishra He already has.  His $value[1] he is trying to do a comparison against is either string `"True"` or string `"False"`.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of $value[1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) is "String" NOT "bool".

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered
>   FALSE:
>
> ```
> the boolean FALSE itself
> the integer 0 (zero)
> the float 0.0 (zero)
> the empty string, and the string "0"
> an array with zero elements
> an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
> ```
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).

reference: [Converting to boolean (PHP Manual)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)

so, **"False" == TRUE** !

maybe you can compare them as string:

```
if(strtoupper($value[1]) == "TRUE"){
    //...
}else{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this should work

```
elseif(!isset($value[1]) || $value[1] === FALSE){
  echo "Company NOT blocked";
}
```

After reading your comment I made this solution. Look stupid but hopefully can work

```
if ($value[1] == "True"){
   echo "Company blocked";
}
elseif($value[1]  == "False"){
   echo "Company NOT blocked";
}
```

Comment: Also now; no echo when I use ===, I'll test with == now.

Comment: Gives me the result of Company blocked when using ==. So still not the correct value. It changes $value[1] into TRUE while it should be FALSE

Comment: +1 for coming up with a reasonable solution for an awkward comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like $value[1] contains the text literal "TRUE" or "FALSE" rather than TRUE or FALSE the booleans.

Change your code to `if (strcasecmp($value[1], "TRUE") == 0)){`  to test if that is the case

```
echo $value[1]; //This gives me the correct result, in this case: FALSE
```

echo will not output booleans like that. and when you cast a string to a boolean if it has any length its true. Causing it always to go the true route

edit:

Your edit confirms this "string(4) "True" Company blockedTrue"   means its not a boolean but a string. The code above should work

Comment: Now it keeps giving me the result of "Company NOT blocked" , regardless if the result is TRUE or FALSE

Comment: Programming languages tend to be case sensitive.  This means they don't know there's a difference between "TrUe" and "TRUE" and "true".  PHP treats them as different strings.  However, the boolean value TRUE is **not** a string.  It is a value of boolean type.  The boolean value TRUE is in no way the same as the string value "True".

Comment: @BLaZuRE look at his var dump it shows a string not a boolean

Comment: if ($value[1] == "TRUE"){
       echo "Company blocked";
      }
      elseif($value[1] == "FALSE"){
       echo "Company NOT blocked";
      } Doesnt give me the correct result

Comment: @user1281385 I understand he's outputting a string, but I feel that he's lacking an understanding between a boolean and a string that contains a word symbolizing a boolean.  I'm trying to help him long-term, rather than for this problem.

Comment: @Marijke ive edited my answer for case insensitve comparions, try that

Comment: Him = her ;) 
When I handle this as a string in my if-statement, I don't get the correct result. Neither when I handle it as a boolean..